# .NET reflection: how to get properties defined on partial class

Tags: c#, .net, linq, entity-framework, reflection

I use the .NET Entity Framework. I want to copy properties from one EntityObject to another. But System.Type.GetProperties() does not seem to return the properties defined on the partial class.

Code:

In XXX.edmx/ XXX.Designer.cs generated by Visual Studio, I have class MyTable:

```
public partial class MyTable: EntityObject{..}
```

I want to add some properties to MyTable class, so I add file XXX.Manual.cs:

```
public partial class MyTable: EntityObject{
    public string myProp{get;set;}
}
```

But `myTableObj.GetType().GetProperties()` does not contain myProp!!!

How can I get myProp using reflection?

**[EDIT]** I want to comment to Alex answer but don't know why the code section is not formated.

Yes, this is very strange.
I use this code to copy properties from Entity to another obj:

```
public static void CopyTo(this EntityObject Entity, EntityObject another){
    var Type = Entity.GetType();
    foreach (var Property in Type.GetProperties()){
        ...
        Property.SetValue(another, Property.GetValue(Entity, null), null);
    }
}
//in some other place:
myTableObj.CopyTo(anotherTableObj);
```

Of couse myTableObj & anotherTableObj is of type MyTable.

When debug into the CopyTo method, VS show that Entity & another is of type MyTable & I can see Entity.myProp, another.myProp

But the Property var in foreach statement simply don't loop to myProp property!

**[EDIT]** Sorry. The code above (CopyTo method) is copy from [diamandiev's answer for another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2185155/cloning-data-on-entity-framework/5560756#5560756)

But his code is wrong: The "break" statement must be replace by "continue" :D

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First of all partial classes is just how source code is split. It does not affect the compiled assembly.

It is likely that you don't see `myProp` property because `myTableObj` is not of type `MyTable`.

Try this:

```
var property = typeof(MyTable).GetProperty("myProp");
```

**[EDIT]**

Just checked:

```
EntityObject x = new MyTable();

var property1 = typeof(MyTable).GetProperty("myProp");
var property2 = x.GetType().GetProperty("myProp");
```

Both `property1` and `property2` returned the property.

**[EDIT]**

Tried your code, it worked after small modification:

```
public static void CopyTo(EntityObject fromEntity, EntityObject toEntity)
{
    foreach (var property in fromEntity.GetType().GetProperties())
    {
        if (property.GetSetMethod() == null)
            continue;
        var value = property.GetValue(fromEntity, null);
        property.SetValue(toEntity, value, null);
    }
}
```

Comment: did you mean "is **not** of type"? If I do `myTableObj.GetType().GetProperties()` as the OP did I get myProp (when myTableObj is of type MyTable). Does EF generate proxies?

Comment: @TrueWill - yes, missed **not**. Thank you.

Comment: @Thành Bùi Việt - I tried your code, it worked after small modification.

Comment: @Thành Bùi Việt - are you sure that your partial classes is in the same namespace? If the namespace is different they will be two separate classes, not one.

Comment: I must be missing something because your last code block with a "small modification" barely resembles the code in the question.  There are so many modifications that I can't tell what actually fixed the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Albeit late, my issue lay in the fact that Visual Studio generated the following code:

```
public System.Windows.Forms.ListView myListView;
```

However, before my ListView would show up in the GetProperties method, I had to do the following:

```
public System.Windows.Forms.ListView myListView { get; set; }
```

Hope this may help out someone else.

Comment: You are correct in the diagnosis, but missed the solution. The solution is not to add get and set, but to use GetFields instead of GetProperties.