# Entity Framework duplicate object and all child properties

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Example structure

```
public class Page
{
    public int PageId { get; set; }
    public string Prop1 { get; set; }
    public string Prop2 { get; set; }
    public virtual List<Section> Sections { get; set; }
}

public class Section
{
    public int SectionId { get; set; }
    public int PageId { get; set; }
    public virtual Page Page { get; set; }
    public virtual List<Heading> Headings { get; set; }
}

public class Heading
{
    public int HeadingId { get; set; }
    public int SectionId { get; set; }
    public virtual Section Section { get; set; }
}
```

It's worth noting that my actual structure has more levels than this but this should be enough to explain what I'm trying to achieve.

So I load my `Page` object I then Clone that object and make some minor changes to the properties of `Page` i.e. `Prop1`, `Prop2`

```
Page pageFromDb = getPageMethod();
Page clonedPage = pageFromDb.Clone();
clonedPage.Prop1 = clonedPage.Prop1 + " Cloned";
addPageMethod(clonedPage); //Adds the page to db
```

In the example above `clonedPage` structure is fine and a new `Page` is added to the database. However I believe because the Id's of the child objects are set and the relationship of the children is always one to many. The original object `pageFromDb` will lose all it children as entity framework instead of creating new `Section` objects for the cloned `Page` will update the `Section.PageId` to the newly inserted page.

I believe a fix for this would be to `foreach`, `foreach`, etc. and set all the Id's to `0` before inserting then entity framework will create new records foreach object. Is there any easier/better way to clone an object in an entity framework environment.?

Comment: What does the Clone method do? Is it doing a deep copy? Can you tell it not to copy the Id Fields? As long as your collections are right, EF will build up the Ids for you after insertions.

Comment: @Tim Just using AutoMapper at the top `Page` object level.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Cloning data on Entity Framework](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2185155/cloning-data-on-entity-framework)

Answer (score 48):

In order for Entity Framework to treat the clone as an entire new object graph when persisting the graph, all entities in the graph need to be **disconnected** from the context in which the root entity was retrieved.

This can be done using the `AsNoTracking` method on the context.

For example, this will pull a page and associated sections graph from the database and turn off tracking. Effectively this is a clone as if you add this to your Page DbSet and save it will create an entirely new object graph in the database. I.e. a new Page entity and new Section entities accordingly. Note, you wont need to call your `Clone` method.

```
var clone = context.Pages
    .AsNoTracking()
    .Including(pages => pages.Sections)
    .Single(...);
context.Pages.Add(clone);
context.SaveChanges(); // creates an entirely new object graph in the database
```

Comment: `Additional information: Conflicting changes to the role 'Section_Page_Target' of the relationship 'Context.Section_Page' have been detected.` I would suggest that even though changes are not being tracked the navigation properties are still populated.

Comment: Hmmm thats weird as the page clone (AsNoTracking) is completely removed from the context and hence can't conflict... Are you loading the original page with a single call to your context as above? Any other work going on against your context other than loading the page and saving the clone?

Comment: Greate post - I have been looking for this for years! Is this deep clone a new feature of C#?

Answer (score 2):

Try this!

```
public Page CopyPage(int pageID)
{
    using(Context context = new Context())
    {
        context.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
        Page dbPage = context.Pages.Where(p => p.PageId == pageID).Include(s => s.Sections.Select(s => s.Section)).First();
        Page page = dbPage.Clone();
        page.PageId = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < dbPage .Sections.Count; i++)
            page.Sections[i] = new Section
            {
                SectionId = 0,
                PageId = 0,
                Page = null,
                Headings = dbPage[i].Headings
            };
        return page;
    }
}

public Page Clone()
    {
        Object page = this.GetType().InvokeMember("", BindingFlags.CreateInstance, null, this, null);

        foreach(PropertyInfo propertyInfo in this.GetType().GetProperties())
        {
            if(propertyInfo.CanWrite)
            {
                propertyInfo.SetValue(page, propertyInfo.GetValue(this, null), null);
            }
        }

        return page;   
    }
```