# Copy Object in EF6 except the Primary Key

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I want to do a copy of an object without copying the ID and without doing it field by field.

Is there anyway?

I'm trying to do this way but I have an Exception:

**The property 'ID' is part of the object's key information and cannot be modified.**

```
Object o = getObject()

Object h = new Object();
h = o;
h.ID = 0;
db.Object.Add(h);
db.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2185155/cloning-data-on-entity-framework

Comment: You should have a look at AutoMapper

Comment: AutoMapper would fit for you, this is the basic configuration. https://www.infoworld.com/article/3192900/c-sharp/how-to-work-with-automapper-in-c.html

Comment: you have to do it field by field, auto mapper does the same on back end and plus it does lot more other things which might not be required in your case.

Answer (score 0):

I used AutoMapper like it's suggested

```
        Object1 o = getObject();
        var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
        {
            cfg.CreateMap<Object1,Object1>();
        });
        var mapper = config.CreateMapper();

        var h = mapper.Map<Object1>(o);



        h.ID = 0;
        db.Object.Add(h);
        db.SaveChanges();
```

And it works.